# Firebase ClassCastException while iterating DataSnapshot

Tags: java, firebase

I'm trying to report a bug to Firebase team, in the site [they recomend to post a question  here instead](https://www.firebase.com/contact.html).

I'm using the latest Java SDK to listen for node change events. While iterating the DataSnapshot object the exception below blows

**Note that the error is inside the library and not in my code.**

Code:

```
        void printData(DataSnapshot data) {
            System.out.println(data.getName() + ":" + data.getValue());
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> it = data.getChildren().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = (DataSnapshot) it.next();
                printData(dataSnapshot);
            }
        }
```

Data:

```
onChildAdded
-e42170ec-a44f-4dcf-9d18-76a39165cea7:{ts=1405260544422, rating=2}
--rating:2
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "FirebaseEventTarget" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.firebase.client.snapshot.LongNode cannot be cast to com.firebase.client.snapshot.ChildrenNode
    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getChildren(DataSnapshot.java:273)
    at Read$1.printData(Read.java:54)
    at Read$1.onChildAdded(Read.java:39)
    at com.firebase.client.core.ChildListenerContainer$1.run(ChildListenerContainer.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: Does that node have children? It looks like it contains a Long value and you are trying to convert it to an object with child nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report! Sorry about that, it looks like that is indeed a bug, it should be returning an empty iterator instead of throwing an exception. I'll have that fixed in the next release of the client. Follow [@FirebaseRelease](https://twitter.com/FirebaseRelease) for notifications about client releases.

In the meantime, you can guard against this by first checking that the DataSnapshot instance has children before calling getChildren() using the hasChildren() method. So your printData method might look something like this:

```
    void printData(DataSnapshot data) {
        System.out.println(data.getName() + ":" + data.getValue());
        if (data.hasChildren()) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> it = data.getChildren().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = (DataSnapshot) it.next();
                printData(dataSnapshot);
            }
        }
    }
```